# How to define conditions in JSON for Spark functions

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to define conditions e.g. for when method. So for example:

```
   people.select(when(col("gender").equalTo("male"), 0)
     .when(col("gender").equalTo("female"), 1)
     .otherwise(2))
```

I want to provide json like:

```
{
  "0": {
    "gender": "male"
  }, 
  "1": {
    "gender": "female" 
  }
}
```

And now using json, I would like to create when condition, using rules from json. Is there any out of the box solution that could help? I couldn't find anyting relevant so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache spark doesn't have an out of the box solution which reads from a json file that has rules embedded within, however in your particular case i would generate the condition in a programmatic manner, the way that you did, rather to have in json file (i would keep in json file if rules changes with high frequency, either modify existing ones or add new ones). If you go for the latter than what you can do is to create a new service that would read, parse the json and create the proper filter condition on the dataframe based on the encounter entities from the json file.

You can take o look [here](https://github.com/el-groucho/jsRules) and use it to extract the needed info from json. Then you need to iterate over the parameters and their values and compose the `when` statements.

Comment: Yes i need json for rules as they will be changed pretty often and by not tech people. Anyway I will parse json to spark rules programmaticaly. I was hoping Spark already has feature like that. Thank you.